# Check User Perms Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I am trying to use Django's default permissions to only show the link to the blog post page if they have the blog post permissions.

The wonderful Django documentation provides the following:

```py
Assuming you have an application with an app_label foo and a model named Bar, 
to test for basic permissions you should use:

    add: user.has_perm('foo.add_bar')
    change: user.has_perm('foo.change_bar')
    delete: user.has_perm('foo.delete_bar')
    view: user.has_perm('foo.view_bar')
```

My app is named `about`

Here is my model:

```py
# models.py
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=250, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog/main')
    content = HTMLField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("post-detail", kwargs={"pk": self.id})
```

Here is my HTML where I am trying to filter

```html
# base.html
          {% if user.has_perm('about.add_blogPost') %}
          <li {% if url_name == 'post' %}class="nav-item active"{% else %}class="nav-item"{% endif %}><a href="{% url 'post' %}" class="nav-link">Add Post</a></li>
          {% endif %}
```

Whenever I follow it just as the documentation has written, I get:
`Could not parse the remainder: '('about.add_blogPost')' from 'user.has_perm('about.add_blogPost')'`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try
{% if user.has_perm 'about.add_blogPost' %}

Comment: what error rised? do you add user in context directly? or try {% if request.user.has_perm 'about.add_blogPost' %}